# How USB redirection works on Remote Machine using RDP ( RemoteFX)

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop, redirection, remote-connection, remotefx

I am a newbie in Remote/cloud technology. I would appreciate your guide.

- I want to use a USB Device on a Remote virtual machine (Windows 10
  Enterprise Edition) plugged into my local Windows 10 machine.
- I have activated RemoteFx feature USB redirection on the local client
  machine and configured USB device under RDP setting.

My USB device is now visible on the **Remote virtual machine** ( ***Windows 10 Enterprise Edition***) using RDP connection ( configured USB Device under RemoteFx section).

But here USB redirection changes the property of USB Device ( Device Serial Number String ) and leads to a device enumeration issue.

---

**Device Serial number string of USB Device on Local Windows 10 machine:**

```
USB\VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX\SSSSSSSSS-SSSSSSSSS
```

Where **SSSSSSSSS-SSSSSSSSS** is Device Serial Number String.

---

**Device Serial number string of USB Device on Remote Virtual Windows 10 machine:**

```
USB\VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX&REV_000X\\3&XXXXXXX&0&TSUSB-SESSION2-XXXXXXXXXX&3&XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Where changed Serial number string **3&XXXXXXX&0&TSUSB-SESSION2-XXXXXXXXXX&3&XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX**

So I would like to know How USB redirection works on Remote Machine using RDP ( RemoteFX)?

Would appreciate it if any Cloud expert/Remote technology expert guide such changes.